# No module named 'torch.nn.functional'

Tags: python, pytorch

I have python file with lines:

```
import argparse
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
```

It generates errors:

```
  File "C:\gdrive\python\a.py", line 5, in <module>
import torch.nn.functional as F
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.nn.functional'
```

How to fix that error?

I have installed pytorch by using command:

```
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have an outdated version of PyTorch. [Conda - `pytorch-cpu`](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch-cpu) was last published over a year ago and its latest version of PyTorch is `1.1.0`, whereas PyTorch is currently at version `1.5.0`. That packages has been abandoned.

You should install PyTorch with the official instructions given on [PyTorch - Get Started locally](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/), by selecting the version you want. In your case that would be Conda with CUDA None (to get the CPU only version).

The resulting command is:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
`from torch.nn import functional as F`

Comment: your solution worked, why does this work and not `import torch.nn.functional as F`?